# Extract date from weirdly formatted datetime polars

Tags: python, datetime, python-polars

```
import polars as pl
df = pl.DataFrame(['2023-08-01T06:13:24.448409',
'2023-08-01T07:29:34.491027'])

print(df.with_columns(pl.col('column_0').str.strptime(pl.Date,'%Y-%m-%d')))
```

So  I have the following mass of code, and for some ungodly reason I cant for the death of me extract the date from those given strings.

In the following example I keep getting the error

```
exceptions.ComputeError: strict date parsing failed for 2 value(s) (2 unique): ["2023-08-01T06:13:24.448409", "2023-08-01T07:29:34.491027"]
```

Any ideas on how can I extract the string from such format of datetime? And why I get this error?

Comment: Is that "T" always in the string? You could potentially just `split` it there and `strptime` the date on its own

Comment: Yes sir, It is interesting enough when I use to datetime in pandas. It works it convert to datetime['ns']. Oh yes that is true  i am gonna try it

Comment: That's a very normal datetime format — it's ISO 8601

Comment: Yeah I also thought so but for some reason it doesnt seen to want to convert

Comment: if you just need the **date** you also extract that first by splitting on `T`, then parsing as usual: `df.with_columns(pl.col('column_0').str.split("T").list.get(0).str.strptime(pl.Date,'%Y-%m-%d'))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To parse a datetime upfront you'll need to provide the full format (date & time) initially then retrieve the date part afterwards. Try the following format:

```
'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f'
```

Comment: Here is the symbol chart https://dtantsur.github.io/rust-openstack/chrono/format/strftime/index.html

Answer (score 3):

The reason for the error is your data is formatted as datetimes, not dates.

You can use [`.str.to_datetime()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.str.to_datetime.html) (same as `str.strptime(pl.Datetime)`)

```py
df.with_columns(pl.col('column_0').str.to_datetime())
```

```
shape: (2, 1)
┌────────────────────────────┐
│ column_0                   │
│ ---                        │
│ datetime[μs]               │
╞════════════════════════════╡
│ 2023-08-01 06:13:24.448409 │
│ 2023-08-01 07:29:34.491027 │
└────────────────────────────┘
```

You can then use the [.dt namespace](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/temporal.html) to extract specific parts if desired.

```py
df.with_columns(pl.col('column_0').str.to_datetime().dt.date())
```

```
shape: (2, 1)
┌────────────┐
│ column_0   │
│ ---        │
│ date       │
╞════════════╡
│ 2023-08-01 │
│ 2023-08-01 │
└────────────┘
```